# Decimal formatting based on number of digits in integer and decimal parts

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

What is the simplest way to format decimal depending on the number of digits in its integer and decimal parts? Lets say a user chooses to see 4 digits, then I have this test case:

```
[('11111.1', '11111'),    # Integer part has >= 4 digits keep only integer part
 ('111.11', '111.1'),     # Integer part has < 4 digits keep total 4 digits
 ('11.111', '11.11'),    
 ('1.1111', '1.111'),
 ('0.00111', '0.0011'),   # Integer part has no digits keep 4 decimal part digits
 ('0.000011', '0.00001')] # First not zero digit place is > 4 keep first digit
```

The solution should allow to choose the number of digits to see.

**Update** Currently I am using a solution which do not allow to choose the number of digits to see:

```
if value >= 1000:
    return '%d' % int(round(value, 0))
elif value >= 100:
    return '%.01f' % value
elif value >= 10:
    return '%.02f' % value
...
```

Comment: what have you already tried? can you show some code you have already been playing with?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean `0.0011` for the fifth value, right?

Comment: Note: in python3 if you call `round` without arguments it will return an integer. Thus doing `int(round(x, 0))` is a more complicated way to write `round(x)`.

Comment: What would you want `1111111` to be?

Comment: @dawg ``1111111`` -> ``1111111``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do everything with a single call to `str.format` using nested formatting parameters:

```
def format_float(value, ndigits=4):
    j = min(i-1 for i in range(ndigits+1) if value >= 10 ** (ndigits - i))
    return '{:.0{num_digits}f}'.format(value, num_digits=max(0,j))
```

The idea is that the number of decimal digits should be equal to the minimum `i` such that the value is greater than `10 ^ (ndigits -i)`. If you specify a number of decimal places of `0` the number is rounded to an integer hence the output is correct.

Example usages:

```
In [66]: inputs = [11111.1, 111.11, 11.111, 1.1111]

In [67]: for inp in inputs:
    ...:     print('Input = {} -- output = {}'.format(inp, format_float(inp, 4)))
Input = 11111.1 -- output = 11111
Input = 111.11 -- output = 111.1
Input = 11.111 -- output = 11.11
Input = 1.1111 -- output = 1.111
```

However this fails with small inputs:

```
In [68]: format_float(0.0001, 4)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-68e3461a51e5> in <module>()
----> 1 format_float(0.0001, 4)

<ipython-input-64-d4485ac4e1c9> in format_float(value, ndigits)
      1 def format_float(value, ndigits=4):
----> 2     j = min(i-1 for i in range(ndigits+1) if value >= 10 ** (ndigits - i))
      3     return '{:.0{num_digits}f}'.format(value, num_digits=max(0,j))

ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

In order to achieve what you want for small numbers we must do something a bit more complex, checking the number of decimal places. In this case is simpler to just convert the number to string and cut the unneeded places.

An attempt could be:

```
def format_float(value, ndigits=4):
    try:
        j = min(i-1 for i in range(ndigits+1) if value >= 10 ** (ndigits - i))
        return '{:.0{num_digits}f}'.format(value, num_digits=max(0,j))
    except ValueError:
        s = '{:.20f}'.format(value).rstrip('0')
        _, dec_part = s.split('.')
        if len(dec_part) > ndigits:
            if set(dec_part[:ndigits]) != {'0'}:
                dec_part = dec_part[:ndigits]
            else:
                for i, char in enumerate(dec_part):
                    if char != '0':
                        dec_part = dec_part[:i+1]
                        break
        if not dec_part:
            # should happen only if the input is 0.0
            return '0'
        else:
            return '{}.{}'.format(0, dec_part)
```

which seems to work for the inputs provided in the question:

```
In [81]: inputs = [11111.1, 111.11, 11.111, 1.1111, 0.00111, 0.000011]

In [82]: for inp in inputs:
    ...:     print('Input = {} -- output = {}'.format(inp, format_float(inp, 4)))
Input = 11111.1 -- output = 11111
Input = 111.11 -- output = 111.1
Input = 11.111 -- output = 11.11
Input = 1.1111 -- output = 1.111
Input = 0.00111 -- output = 0.0011
Input = 1.1e-05 -- output = 0.00001
```

This does not handle negative numbers, but it's quite easy to check for them and work with the absolute value:

```
def format_float(value, ndigits):
    sign = ''
    if value < 0:
        value = abs(value)
        sign = '-'

    if value >= 1:
        j = min(i-1 for i in range(ndigits+1) if value >= 10 ** (ndigits - i))
        return '{}{:.0{num_digits}f}'.format(sign, value, num_digits=max(0,j))
    s = '{:.17f}'.format(value).rstrip('0')
    _, dec_part = s.split('.')
    if not dec_part:
        # Happens only with 0.0
        return '0'
    if len(dec_part) < ndigits or set(dec_part[:ndigits]) != {'0'}:
        # truncate the decimal representation
        dec_part = dec_part.ljust(ndigits, '0')[:ndigits]
    elif len(dec_part) > ndigits:
        # too small. Just find the first decimal place
        for i, char in enumerate(dec_part):
            if char != '0':
                dec_part = dec_part[:i+1]
                break
    return '{}{}.{}'.format(sign, 0, dec_part)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need get decimal level before you sort it in different lists

```
import math

def get_decimal_level(number):
    return int(round(math.log(number, 10), 10)) + 1
```

Test it

```
>>> get_decimal_level(99999)
5
>>> get_decimal_level(100000)
6
```

Make it work

```
from collections import defaultdict

def group_list_on_levels(numbers):
    group_numbers = defaultdict(list)

    for number in numbers:
        group_numbers[get_decimal_level(number)].append(number)

    levels = group_numbers.keys()
    levels.sort(reverse=True)

    return [group_numbers[key] for level in levels]

numbers = [31243,543543.654,543543,0.001]
final_list = group_list_on_levels(numbers)
print(final_list) # Check your answer
```

In console I get

```
[[543543.654, 543543], [31243], [0.001]]
```

P.S. And no decimal-string transformations

Answer (score -1):

Don't see easy one-two lines solution. The code below solves your problem.

```
def formatNumber(a, DIGITS_TO_KEEP):
    p = a.index('.')
    if p >= DIGITS_TO_KEEP:
        return a[:p]
    else:
        q = 0
        while q+1 < len(a) and (a[q]=='.' or a[q]=='0'):
            q += 1
        return a[:max(DIGITS_TO_KEEP, q)+1]

for case in ['11111.1', '111.11', '11.111', '1.1111', '0.00111', '0.000011']:
    print case, ":", formatNumber(case, 4)
```